# How to use shared preferences to save token in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to keep the user token in after the user successfully login in flutter.I am trying to save device token to SharedPreferences so I can use it in other widgets,but error is always : Invalid argument(s) (value): Must not be null . How i can save ID and access token ?

My code :

```
Future<User> login(String username, String password) async {
    await checkInternet();

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, String> body = {'username': username, 'password': password};

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.AUTH_LOGIN),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // print(body);
        var data = body['user'];
        // print(data);
        User user = User.fromJson(data);
        await _saveUser(user.id, user.access_token);
        return user;
      case 404:
        throw ResourceNotFound('User');
        break;
      case 422:
        throw UnProcessedEntity();
        break;
      case 401:
        throw LoginFailed();
      default:
        return null;
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveUser(int id, String access_token) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setInt('id', id);
    sharedPreferences.setString('access_token', access_token);
  }
}
```

and rhis the user model :

```
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String username;
  String phone;
  String access_token;
  String activeboxe_id;
  String adress;
  DateTime email_verifed_at;

  User(this.name, this.email, this.username, this.phone, this.activeboxe_id,
      this.adress, this.email_verifed_at,
      [this.access_token, this.id]);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject) {
    this.id = jsonObject['id'];
    this.name = jsonObject['name'];
    this.email = jsonObject['email'];
    this.phone = jsonObject['phone'];
    this.access_token = jsonObject['access_token'];
    this.activeboxe_id = jsonObject['activeboxe_id'];
    this.adress = jsonObject['adress'];
    this.email_verifed_at = jsonObject['email_verifed_at'];
    this.username = jsonObject['username'];
  }
}
```

Comment: As per your question, It seems that the id value is null. Please check the value you are getting from the response.

Comment: i checked it . id = 10 from response

Comment: Then you can store the value just after the response 200 response. Your issue will be solved.

Comment: the access_ token attribut is outside user model . it's in the body. how i can save it correctly ? the id is works fine Raju Gupta

Comment: For me your code is perfect. Please verify once again the value of ID and token and check the runtime type.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the values you are trying to save are not null and `setInt` or `setString` is an `async` function so you need to add `await` before them

```dart
Future<void> _saveUser(int id, String access_token) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setInt('id', id);
    await sharedPreferences.setString('access_token', access_token);
  }
```

And your `User` class is not return the `.fromJson` if you have noticed

```dart
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String username;
  String phone;
  String access_token;
  String activeboxe_id;
  String adress;
  DateTime email_verifed_at;

  User(this.name, this.email, this.username, this.phone, this.activeboxe_id,
      this.adress, this.email_verifed_at,
      [this.access_token, this.id]);
  
// return a User object here
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject) => User({
    this.id = jsonObject['id'];
    this.name = jsonObject['name'];
    this.email = jsonObject['email'];
    this.phone = jsonObject['phone'];
    this.access_token = jsonObject['access_token'];
    this.activeboxe_id = jsonObject['activeboxe_id'];
    this.adress = jsonObject['adress'];
    this.email_verifed_at = jsonObject['email_verifed_at'];
    this.username = jsonObject['username'];
  });
}
```

Comment: Constructors can't have a return type.

Comment: How i can return a User object ?